# Snap application and Word

Tags: wpf, windows, aero

I'm making an application that I want the user to be able to click a button, that snaps Word or another program to take up 70% of the screen, and my application to take up the remaining 30%.

**Is this possible?**

**Is there a native way to do it?**

**Is there a third party way to do it?**

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is indeed possible, try this function:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, ref Rectangle rectangle);
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, int WPARAM, int LPARAM);
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int, Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

public const uint WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
public const int SC_NEXTWINDOW = 0xF040;
public static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
public static readonly IntPtr HWND_NOTOPMOST = new IntPtr(-2);
public static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOP = new IntPtr(0);
public static readonly IntPtr HWND_BOTTOM = new IntPtr(1);
public const UInt32 TOPMOST_FLAGS = 0x0002 | 0x0001;

Public void resisezeWindow(String procesname, int Width, int Height, Boolean bringtofront)
{
    foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcesses())
    {
        IntPtr id = proc.MainWindowHandle;
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        GetWindowRect(id, ref rect);
        if (proc.MainWindowTitle.Contains(procesname))
        {
            PostMessage(proc.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_NEXTWINDOW, 0);
                    MoveWindow(id, 0, 0, Width, Height, true);
                    if(bringtofront) SetWindowPos(id, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, TOPMOST_FLAGS);
                    proc.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

Klik [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945923/possible-to-control-other-programs-windows/13948273#13948273) to see the original question.